# Difference between current equations of enhancement and depletion mode MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

1)Are the equations and operating region conditions the same for both enhancement and depletion type MOSFET? Are [these](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/fa05/handouts/discussions/Discussion5.pdf) equations and operating conditions valid for both enhancement and depletion type MOSFET?

2)If they are the same then what things(difference) should I take into account while evaluating enhancement and depletion mode MOSFET circuits.

Answer (score 1):

The physical difference between enhancement and depletion MOSFETs is that enhancement MOSFETs have an additional doping applied to them which **increases the threshold voltage \$V_t\$.**

So the same formulas do apply only the **value of \$V_t\$** is different.

For an enhancement NMOS \$V_t\$ can for example be 0.5 V. That means that when \$V_{gs}\$ = 0 V no drain current can flow.

For a depletion NMOS \$V_t\$ can for example be - 0.5 V. That means that when \$V_{gs}\$ = 0 V a drain current **can** flow.

To shut off a depletion NMOS a **negative \$V_{gs}\$** would be needed.

In practice you will almost never encounter depletion type MOSFETs because they're not so well suited for switching and logic circuits because they're not so easy to switch off. Depletion MOSFETs are sometimes used as RF amplifiers though.

Comment: So we can identify a depletion NMOS if its threshold voltage is negative. If the threshold voltage is positive then the NMOS is enhancement mode NMOS?